# How to display some text in a GridView button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following code which is a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="BookingResults" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" OnRowCommand="BookingResults_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField Text=" " ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ViewAll"  HeaderText="Show Guideline" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    </asp:ButtonField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Topic" HeaderText="Topic" SortExpression="Topic" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Specialty" HeaderText="Specialty" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Provider" HeaderText="Provider" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Summary") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Guideline" HeaderText="Guideline" />
                </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
```

The end result is this:

[image]

I can't seem to give the `ButtonField` an ID so I can display text per line. How can I display an increment value from 1 and so forth in the button from code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap into RowDataBound event, and add the logic:

```
var btn = (IButtonControl)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
btn.Text = indexVariable;
```

The button is usually the first control of the cell you defined it, which since it's the first column, would be cell index zero.

Comment: I have a line `Results.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));` so should `e` be `Results`?

Comment: No, your code doesn't reflect the situation you are mentioning, so what is Results, datatable?

Comment: Yes it is the data table. I think I have to call that on RowBound function for it to work?

Comment: Well, you could just prepopulate every row with a unique ID and then bind that to the table.  If that solves the problem, that would be your best bet...  Otherwise yes, RowDataBound.